# Razor inline casting not working - proper syntax needed

Tags: razor, type-conversion

does anyone have  ideas on why using the local variable is fine, but casting inline doesn't work?  I'm obviously missing something here but I can't see it.

```
   @if (Model is ISectionInformationProvider)
   {
       ISectionInformationProvider local = (ISectionInformationProvider)Model;

       @* The line below just prints as text *@ 
       <h1>@((ISectionInformationProvider)Model).SectionTitle</h1> 

       @* These work just fine *@
       <h1>@local.SectionTitle</h1>
       <p>@local.SectionDescription</p>
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<h1>@(((ISectionInformationProvider)Model).SectionTitle)</h1>
```

Comment: Think that's the only permutation I didn't try!  It didn't seem natural to do that.  Thanks.  Will mark as accepted as soon as I can